# Why is the ReturnType of 'value is Type' function boolean?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I want to make function that receive value and run type guard function.

```
const checkType = (string: string) : string is 'a' => string === 'a'
/// const checkType: (string: string) => string is "a"

const getType = (value: 'a' | 'b') => checkType(value);
/// const getType: (value: 'a' | 'b') => boolean
```

I expected return type of `getType` to be `string is 'a'` but it is predicated as `boolean`.

Can the `{value} is {Type}` return guard work on in one function?

Can't it be conveyed to another function?

Comment: `string is 'a'` is not a type. Type guard always returns `boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type `string is 'a'` just conveys typescript that it is a type guard. It will anyway return a `boolean`, since type guards are used to confirm types in runtime.

> Can't it be conveyed to another function?

Yes, you can add the guard function in an `if` statement as given below. This will make sure if the guard check passes in runtime, it practically confirms that it's of the given type.

```
const isLiteralA = (string: string) : string is 'a' => string === 'a'

function myFunction(stringValue: string) {
  if (isLiteralA(stringValue)) {
    // Any operation on `stringValue` inside this if statement will assume it to be
    // the string literal "a" since stringValue passed the guard check for the same
  }
  else {
    // If `stringValue` does not pass the guard check, do something else (if required)
  }
}
```

You may refer to: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates